# Type definition from array of object to object

Tags: typescript

How do I rewrite the code to get rid of explicit casts?

```
type A={a:number};
type B={b:string};


let a:A={a:0};
let b:B={b:''};

function arrayToObject<T>(array:T[]):T {
    return array.reduce((r,c) =>Object.assign(r,c))
}

let result = arrayToObject([a,b]);//expects A&B instead A|B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to convert a union type into an intersection type. This is also evident by the way `Object.assign` is defined:

```
assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;  
assign<T, U, V>(target: T, source1: U, source2: V): T & U & V;
assign<T, U, V, W>(target: T, source1: U, source2: V, source3: W): T & U & V & W;
assign(target: object, ...sources: any[]): any;
```

`lib.d.ts` provides several strongly typed versions for up to 3 sources, and for more `sources` just becomes an array of `any` with no type safety.

You could use a similar approach:

```
// Public signatures 
function arrayToObject<T>(array:[T]):T
function arrayToObject<T, T2>(array:[T, T2]):T & T2
function arrayToObject<T, T2, T3>(array:[T, T2, T3]):T & T2 & T3
function arrayToObject<T, T2, T3, T4>(array:[T, T2, T3, T4]):T & T2 & T3 & T4
function arrayToObject<T>(array:T[]):T // for more or dynamic values
// Implementation signature
function arrayToObject<T>(array:T[]):T {
    return array.reduce((r,c) =>Object.assign(r,c))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is that reduce has the type: `(T, T): T` which causes Object.assign to believe that it also has the type `(T, T): T`.

So the problem is that you want to do this for an arbitrary length array, if you instead had a distinct number of elements in the array you could unwrap the loop and use the form ``Òbject.assign(A, B): A&B```.

But what you want is probably not possible in Typescript since you need to create a type for the result of the function which is the intersection type of an arbitrary array of union type. If you could declare such a type you could then just replace reduce with a loop.